# Dropdown list values repeating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using dropdown list values Bound from data base my code

```
Public Function get_type() As String
        'get type
        If IsPostBack = False Then
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select (type) from prod_type", con)
            da.Fill(ds, "prod_type")
            ddtype.DataSource = ds
            ddtype.DataTextField = "type"
            ddtype.DataValueField = "type"
            ddtype.DataBind()
            da.Dispose()
            ds.Dispose()
            con.Close()
        End If
```

I call this function in page load

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. if you do have a question please state that.

Comment: Are you storing your DataSet f.e. in Session? @naveen: the question is why the values in DropDownList are repeating. I assume that the DataSet doesn't get cleared because he's storing it in Session or even in Cache.

Comment: then you are calling `get_type()` more than once during page's lifecycle. You could prevent it by setting DataAdapter's `ClearBeforeFill` property to `true`.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter where to add this property  ClearBeforeFill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify it like this:

```
Public Function get_type() As String
    'get type
    If IsPostBack = False Then
        ds.Clear() //new
        ddtype.Items.Clear() //new
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select (type) from prod_type", con)
        da.Fill(ds, "prod_type")
        ddtype.DataSource = ds
        ddtype.DataTextField = "type"
        ddtype.DataValueField = "type"
        ddtype.DataBind()
        da.Dispose()
        ds.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    End If
```

And if you still have duplicate entries it should be because you have duplicates in the database.

Comment: @evigneesh your wellcome! You probably had residual data in the data set at the time of this function call.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: ignore this, it's wrong:

This is a SQL question not a asp.net or VB question.
Your sql won't select unique 'types' from your prod_type table.  Execute the following SQL:

```
select distinct(type) from prod_type
```

Also read the posting FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @evigneesh do you see different results for both queries or the same?

Comment: same because my table does not having repeated values

Comment: @evigneesh ignore my advice, sorry

Comment: you helped me lot please keep sorry away

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases where the values would be duplicated in the `DropDownList` here:

1. There are duplicated values in the database.
2. You are calling the function multiple times at the first loading of the page.

You can solve the first case by using [DISTINCT](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/) in your select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM prod_type
```

You can solve the second by setting the value of the `TableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill` property to *true*.

Comment: How to use this property TableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill

Comment: @evigneesh: Forget about it. Instead place the following: `ds.Tables["prod_type"].Clear();` before initializing the data adapter.